# WSO2 EMM - Check iOS user has removed MDM profile from device

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-iot

I am trying to check if a user has removed iOS MDM profile from mobile directly. (this is for non-supervised phone)

A user can remove profile in online & offline mode.

While online, if a user removes the MDM profile I am able to detect by getting the status of a device.

But, when a user removes the profile by going to offline mode, WSO2 EMM still displays the device as active.

Edited:
My iOS application is also installed on the device. So if there is any objective-c way to detect iOS profile installed on a system will also do the job.

Let me know if you need additional details. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- If user remove the profile while the devices is connected to the EMM sever (online) an unregistered request will be send to the server in sever side device will be listed as unregistered.
- If user remove the profile while device is not connected to the EMM sever(offline), the device will be in the inactive state until the device is property connected to the emm sever.

Comment: We tried checking that. Even if user is in offline mode, device shown as Active. Device is only inactive when it's removed in online mode

Comment: This is a limitation in EMM you need to have a active policy applied o the device in order to change the status to inactive.